# incrementing values ​in awk or bash

Tags: bash, awk

Below is a fragment of a .pdb file:

```
ATOM     52  OXT GLU     5     -23.455 -21.595  12.691  0.00  0.00
TER
ATOM      1  N   MET A   1      -9.976  22.279  65.378  1.00 37.35           N
ATOM      2  H   MET A   1      -9.180  21.915  65.882  1.00 37.35           H
```

I want to write a script in bash or awk that will increment the value of the second column in the line before the first "TER" in the .pdb file by +1 and these values will be saved to the second column in the lines directly after "TER". Specifically, I am looking for something like this:

```
ATOM 52 OXT GLU 5 -23.455 -21.595 12.691 0.00 0.00
TER
ATOM 53 N MET A 1 -9.976 22.279 65.378 1.00 37.35 N
ATOM 54 H MET A 1 -9.180 21.915 65.882 1.00 37.35 H
```

I tried something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the value of the second column in the last line before "TER"
last_col2=$(grep -v "TER" model.pdb | awk '{if($2>max){max=$2}}END{print max}')
new_col2=$((last_col2+1))

# Loop through the lines of the input file
while read line; do
  if [[ "$line" == "TER" ]]; then
    # Skip "TER" line, but print it to the output file
    echo "$line" >> model_new.pdb
  else
    # Increment the second and fifth columns for lines after "TER"
    # and print the updated line to the output file
    col2=$(echo "$line" | cut -c 7-11 | tr -d '[:space:]')
    if [[ "$col2" -eq 1 ]]; then
      new_line=$(echo "$line" | sed "s/$col2/$new_col2/")
      echo "$new_line" >> model_new.pdb
    else
      echo "$line" >> model_new.pdb
    fi
  fi
done < model.pdb
```

But it doesn't work. Do you help me ?

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Please provide a more descriptive explanation than a plain _it doesn't work_. Aside from this, your approach is terribly slow: For each, you create at least 3 child processes. If you want to do it in bash, do it completely in bash, instead of using `cut` and `tr` and `sed`. By and large, I think it's much less work if you do it in `awk` or `Ruby` or something along that line.

Answer (score 5):

> will increment the value of the second column in the line before the first "TER" in the .pdb file by +1 and these values will be saved to the second column in the lines directly after "TER"

```
awk '
  seenTer{ $2 = ++beforeTerValue }
  /TER/{ seenTer=1 }
  !seenTer{ beforeTerValue = $2 }
  1
' inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: I want increment values in 6th column also:

ATOM 53 N MET A 6 -9.976 22.279 65.378 1.00 37.35 N
ATOM 54 H MET A 6 -9.180 21.915 65.882 1.00 37.35 H

Comment: https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '__ ? $(!_+!_) = (++___)_ : (__ += /TER/) || ___ = _$(!_+!_)'
```

---

```
ATOM     52  OXT GLU     5     -23.455 -21.595  12.691  0.00  0.00
TER
ATOM 53 N MET A 1 -9.976 22.279 65.378 1.00 37.35 N
ATOM 54 H MET A 1 -9.180 21.915 65.882 1.00 37.35 H
```

---

*The 1 extra underscore at* `(++___)_` *and* `_$(!_+!_)` *aren't typos - those are string concats with an empty string* (aka `null string`) *which ensures output in the unlikely case with starting value of `0`*

*I wrote the 2nd one with underscore before* `_$(..` *to illustrate that, unlike* `perl` or most `Unix/Linux` shells, `"_"` *isn't a special variable at all*