# renumbering values in .pdb file

Tags: bash, macos, awk, pdb

I have one .pdb file, which correspond to peptide-protein complex. Fragment of this file looks like this:

<sup>**edit: replaced the sample input with a subset of what OP provided afterwards.**</sup>

```
ATOM     51  O   ARG     4      18.189  21.505 -30.356  0.00  0.00
ATOM     52  OXT ARG     5      19.822  21.322 -27.773  0.00  0.00
TER
ATOM      1  N   MET A   1      -9.976  22.279  65.378  1.00 37.35           N
ATOM      2  H   MET A   1      -9.180  21.915  65.882  1.00 37.35           H
ATOM      3  N   LYS A   2     -11.970  21.837  62.804  1.00 40.65           N
ATOM      4  H   LYS A   2     -11.194  21.438  62.295  1.00 40.65           H
```

I want change numeration 6th column for all lines directly after first "TER" line in my .pdb file. Now, numeration in 6th column start from 1 but I want, that numeration in 6th column started in the same way as above, but started with 6 instead of 1.

Additionally, I want change numeration in 2nd column for all lines also directly after first "TER" line in my .pdb file. Now, numeration in 2nd column start from 1 but I want, that numeration in 2nd column started in the same way as above, but started with 53 instead of 1.

<sub>**edit: added an expected output that illustrates OP's original goal.**</sub>

The expected output would be:

```
ATOM 51 O ARG 4 18.189 21.505 -30.356 0.00 0.00
ATOM 52 OXT ARG 5 19.822 21.322 -27.773 0.00 0.00
TER
ATOM 53 N MET A 6 -9.976 22.279 65.378 1.00 37.35 N
ATOM 54 H MET A 6 -9.180 21.915 65.882 1.00 37.35 H
ATOM 55 N LYS A 7 -11.970 21.837 62.804 1.00 40.65 N
ATOM 56 H LYS A 7 -11.194 21.438 62.295 1.00 40.65 H
```

**Can You help me ?**

I tried doing this by using bash script, but when I'm opening my edited .pdb file in Pymol I have something like this

[image]

This is my code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# read input file and output file names from command line arguments
input_file=complex.pdb
output_file=renum.pdb

# initialize residue counter and flag for tracking first "TER" occurrence
residue_num=1
ter_found=false

# loop through the lines of the input file
while read line
do
    # check if the line contains "TER"
    if [[ "$line" == "TER" ]]
    then
        # if it does, reset the residue counter to 5 and set the flag to true
        residue_num=5
        ter_found=true
    else
        # if it doesn't, extract the residue name and chain ID from the line
        residue_name=$(echo $line | awk '{print $4}')
        chain_id=$(echo $line | awk '{print $5}')

        # if the residue name or chain ID has changed, increment the residue counter
        if [[ "$residue_name" != "$prev_residue_name" || "$chain_id" != "$prev_chain_id" ]]
        then
            residue_num=$((residue_num+1))
        fi

        # if the first "TER" has been found, replace the 6th column with the new residue number
        if [[ "$ter_found" == true ]]
        then
            line=$(echo $line | awk -v num="$residue_num" '{$6=num; print}')
        fi

        # save the current residue name and chain ID for comparison in the next iteration
        prev_residue_name=$residue_name
        prev_chain_id=$chain_id
    fi

    # write the modified line to the output file
    echo $line >> $output_file
done < $input_file
```

Finally my renum.pdb file looks like this (this is only fragment this .pdb file):

<sup>**edit: The following output was generated by processing the "updated" input with OP's code.**</sup>

```
ATOM 51 O ARG 4 18.189 21.505 -30.356 0.00 0.00
ATOM 52 OXT ARG 5 19.822 21.322 -27.773 0.00 0.00
TER
ATOM 1 N MET A 6 -9.976 22.279 65.378 1.00 37.35 N
ATOM 2 H MET A 6 -9.180 21.915 65.882 1.00 37.35 H
ATOM 3 N LYS A 7 -11.970 21.837 62.804 1.00 40.65 N
ATOM 4 H LYS A 7 -11.194 21.438 62.295 1.00 40.65 H
```

Comment: You should add the expected output to your question (instead of the wrong one returned by your code), that would make it easier to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: You should be doing this with a single awk script called once from shell, not multiple awk scripts called multiple times in a shell loop - see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output for the sample input you provided so we don't have to guess at what it should be.

Comment: You say "I want, that numeration in 6th column started in the same way as above, but started with 6 instead of 1" - it's not clear if that means you want those values to start with 6 and keep incrementing (as I guessed in my answer), or you want them all to be exactly 6 (as @Fravadona guessed in their answer). Posting the expected output would clarify that requirement.

Comment: [I see](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75984691/1745001) you ignored the advice and answer you got when you asked a very similar question a few days ago.

Comment: I tried this code:
awk '
  seenTer{ $2 = ++beforeTerValue }
  /TER/{ seenTer=1 }
  !seenTer{ beforeTerValue = $2 }
  1
' inputfile > outputfile

but I have something like this in output file:
ATOM 53 N MET A 1 -9.976 22.279 65.378 1.00 37.35 N

Spacing between neighboring columns are too small and I get the similar projection 3D to today attached

Comment: Nevertheless, [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75984754/1745001) is the correct answer to [the question you asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75984691/1745001) (which didn't ask to retain spacing in the output) and it's a much better starting point for anything else you need to do than the shell script you posted there or here for the reasons listed in [the article I referenced](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) in my comments there and here and others.

Comment: ok i didn't understand you earlier. I try again edit my post with input data

Comment: @skywalker I completely edited your question for it to contain only the necessary info. Also, your question is about **your code** & problem, not **my code**, so you shouldn't be including my answer in the question... I updated my answer for it to process the sample input correctly. If you happen to experience other border cases that aren't processed correctly then ask a new question about it instead of editing this one. Also, don't forget to **accept** my answer if it does the expected job.

Answer (score 2):

A PDB has fixed-width columns, so you **shouldn't** transform it into a single-space delimited file because the other programs won't be able to process it afterwards.

For an **ATOM** record, the specification is:

| COLUMNS & (width) | DATA TYPE | FIELD | DEFINITION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 - 6 (6) | String(6) | recordName | "`ATOM` " |
| 7 - 11 (5) | Integer | serial | Atom serial number |
| 12 (1) | - | - | - |
| 13 - 16 (4) | Atom | name | Atom name |
| 17 (1) | Character | altLoc | Alternate location indicator |
| 18 - 20 (3) | Residue name | resName | Residue name |
| 21 (1) | - | - | - |
| 22 (1) | Character | chainID | Chain identifier |
| 23 - 26 (4) | Integer | resSeq | Residue sequence number |
| 27 (1) | AChar | iCode | Code for insertion of residues |
| 28 - 30 (3) | - | - | - |
| 31 - 38 (8) | Real(8.3) | x | Orthogonal coordinates for X in Å |
| 39 - 46 (8) | Real(8.3) | y | Orthogonal coordinates for Y in Å |
| 47 - 54 (8) | Real(8.3) | z | Orthogonal coordinates for Z in Å |
| 55 - 60 (6) | Real(6.2) | occupancy | Occupancy |
| 61 - 66 (6) | Real(6.2) | tempFactor | Temperature factor |
| 67 - 76 (10) | - | - | - |
| 77 - 78 (2) | LString(2) | element | Element symbol, right-justified |
| 79 - 80 (2) | LString(2) | charge | Charge on the atom |

For processing it with any `awk`, you can use `substr` to extract the relevant parts:

```bash
awk '
    /^TER/  { after_TER = 1 }
    /^ATOM/ {
        if (after_TER) {
            resName = substr($0,18,3)
            if ( resName != previous_resName ) {
                previous_resName = resName
                resSeq = sprintf("%4d", resSeq + 1)
            }
            $0 = substr($0,1,6) \
                 sprintf("%5d", ++serial) \
                 substr($0,12,11) \
                 resSeq \
                 substr($0,27)
        } else {
            serial = substr($0,7,5)
            resSeq = substr($0,23,4)
        }
    }
    { print }
' mod.pdb > renum.pdb
```

###### Example

Input:

```
ATOM     51  O   ARG     4      18.189  21.505 -30.356  0.00  0.00
ATOM     52  OXT ARG     5      19.822  21.322 -27.773  0.00  0.00
TER
ATOM      1  N   MET A   1      -9.976  22.279  65.378  1.00 37.35           N
ATOM      2  H   MET A   1      -9.180  21.915  65.882  1.00 37.35           H
ATOM      3  N   LYS A   2     -11.970  21.837  62.804  1.00 40.65           N
ATOM      4  H   LYS A   2     -11.194  21.438  62.295  1.00 40.65           H
```

Output:

```
ATOM     51  O   ARG     4      18.189  21.505 -30.356  0.00  0.00
ATOM     52  OXT ARG     5      19.822  21.322 -27.773  0.00  0.00
TER
ATOM     53  N   MET A   6      -9.976  22.279  65.378  1.00 37.35           N
ATOM     54  H   MET A   6      -9.180  21.915  65.882  1.00 37.35           H
ATOM     55  N   LYS A   7     -11.970  21.837  62.804  1.00 40.65           N
ATOM     56  H   LYS A   7     -11.194  21.438  62.295  1.00 40.65           H
```

Comment: It works, but in one of my complex renumbering in the sixth column is not taken into account

Comment: It works, but in one of my complex renumbering in the sixth column is not taken into account

Previously, I had problems with renumbering in two complexes. When I run your updated code I have the same problem with only one complex:

ATOM     52  OXT ASP     5     -22.381 -24.231   9.519  0.00  0.00

TER

ATOM     53  N   MET A   5      -9.976  22.279  65.378  1.00 37.35           N

In above fragment of my output file renumbering in the sixth column is not taken into account. Can you help me @Fravadona solve this problem ?

Comment: I can’t reproduce the problem with those three lines, so I cannot help without further input. You should add a better example by editing your question, a few lines per residue

Comment: I want change numeration in 6th column for all lines directly after "TER" line. I want , that numeration starting from 6 instead 5. This is a fragment my output .pdb file, which was obtained by using your updated script:

ATOM     52  OXT ASP     5     -22.381 -24.231   9.519  0.00  0.00
TER
ATOM     53  N   MET A   5      -9.976  22.279  65.378  1.00 37.35           N
.......
ATOM     72  N   LYS A   6     -11.970  21.837  62.804  1.00 40.65           N

I can't introduce in my comments longer fragment output .pdb file :(

Comment: @skywalker You can edit your question with https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76216504/edit . What's important to add is an example of input that doesn't work